# gradient of a numerical function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

Is there a way other than interpolation to evaluate the numerical differentiation using Mathematica? I have a function A(x,y) and I want to obtain the gradient of this function.

```
A = {0.46111275151112086` + 0.1978937346142066` I, 
  0.46111285190349904` + 0.19789374031698123` I, 
  0.46111315307881984` + 0.19789375742522503` I, 
  0.46111365503164287` + 0.19789378593869741` I, 
  0.4611143577529007` + 0.19789382585699725` I, 
  0.46111526122989965` + 0.1978938771795634` I, 
  0.4611163654463202` + 0.19789393990567397` I};

x = {0.`, 0.00006124745693864213`, 
  0.0001224943093896109`, 
   0.0001837399528711989`, 0.0002449837829136309`, 
   0.00030622519506502953`, 0.0003674635848973809`};

y = {0.019495703116316185`, 0.019495606908956676`, 
  0.019495318287827666`, 0.019494837255777733`, 
   0.01949416381755447`, 0.019493297979804442`, 
    0.01949223975107312`};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot get the full gradien of $A(x,y)$ because the points $(x_i,y_i)$ that you gave are too ill-poised. They look as if you had sampled them from a curve. Is that correct? You can of course estimate the directionalal derivatice of `A` along that curves. Is that whay you mean? Instead of an interpolation, I would propose to estimate the derivative by a low order polynomial fit.

Comment: Yes, the data I provided are an example because I had a huge data. Can you please apply the way you mentioned on my example.? Sorry, I am a beginner in Mathematica.